# SQL Server: catch every error within a database into error table

Tags: sql-server, database, error-handling, try-catch, hook

I wonder how do I hook a certain database in SQL Server in a way that every error that is being thrown, and no one catches, will be caught and saved into an `error_table` in my database. Thanks.

Comment: You could use Extended Events to capture `sqlserver.error_reported`. Check out [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35015/log-all-errors-in-queries) question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an alert to do this: To create an alert using an error number

```
In Object Explorer, click the plus sign to expand the server where you want to create an alert using an error number.

Click the plus sign to expand SQL Server Agent.

Right-click Alerts and select New Alert.

In the New Alert dialog box, in the Name box, enter a name for this alert.
Check the Enable check box to enable the alert to run. By default, Enable is checked.

In the Type list, select SQL Server event alert.

Under Event alert definition, in the Database name list, select a database to restrict the alert to a specific database.

Under Alerts will be raised based on, Click Severity and then select the specific severity that will raise the alert.
You can add a job step to write to a table with the information from the alert.
```